# Laplace transform of $x^{3/2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the Laplace transform of $x^{3/2}$

$L[x^{3/2}]=L[x (x^{1/2})]=-\frac{d}{dp}L[x^{1/2}]=-\frac{d}{dp}L[x(x^{-1/2})]=-\frac{d}{dp}(-\frac{d}{dp})\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{p}}=\frac{1}{2p}\frac{1}{2p}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{p}}=\frac{1}{4p^2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{p}}$

The correct answer is $\frac{3}{4p^2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{p}}$, could someone tell me where I missed the $3$ please?

Comment: Hint: Gamma function.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I almost solved it could you please help me find my mistake?

Comment: Kinda tied up at the moment. When I get a chance I'll post an answer. Please be patient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the correct way to do the integral.

\begin{align*}
\int_0 ^\infty e^{-st} t^{3/2} \ dt &= \int_0 ^\infty e^{-u} \left(\frac{u}{s} \right)^{3/2} \ \frac{du}{s} \\
&= \frac{1}{s^{5/2}} \int_0 ^\infty e^{-u} u^{\frac{5}{2}-1} \ du \\
&= \frac{1}{s^{5/2}} \Gamma \left( \frac{5}{2} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{s^{5/2}} \cdot \frac{3\sqrt{\pi}}{4}
\end{align*}

The change of variables $u = st$ was used, and tables were used to evaluate the particular value of the gamma function.