# Can someone tell me why this is wrong

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

$L[t*\sqrt{t}]
= L[t*t^{1/2}]
= L[t^{3/2}]$

$L[t^{n}] =\frac{\Gamma n}{s^{n+1}}$    so   $L[t^{3/2}]= \frac{\Gamma \frac {3}{2}}{s^\frac {5}{2}}$

$ = \frac{\frac {1}{2} \Gamma \frac {1}{2}}{s^\frac {5}{2}}$

$ = \frac {\sqrt{\pi}} {2 s^\frac {5}{2}}$

but my texbook and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2346760/laplace-transform-of-x3-2) says that the correct answer is $\frac{1}{s^{5/2}} \cdot \frac{3\sqrt{\pi}}{4}$

where did I make a mistake?

Comment: What do you mean by $\Rightarrow$?

Comment: $L[t^{n}] =\frac{\Gamma (\color{red}{n+1})}{s^{n+1}}$

Comment: You wish to evaluate $\Gamma(\frac{5}{2})$, not $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})$.

Comment: @Théophile Changed it to =

Comment: @cosmo5 thank you, my bad

Comment: Please be careful with the multiplication signs, $*$ is for convolution, which is a common operation under the Laplace transform, as $L(f*g)=L(f)·L(g)$ etc.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in [Laplace transformation](http://www.math.umd.edu/%7Ehking/Laplace.pdf), $$ F(p)={\mathcal{L}}\left\{ x^n:p \right\}=\dfrac{\Gamma(n+1)}{p^{n+1}}~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{for}~~~p >-1$$
and $$ F(p)={\mathcal{L}}\left\{ x^n:p \right\}=\dfrac{n!}{p^{n+1}}~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{for}~~~p =0,~1,~2,~\cdots$$
For your case $~n=3/2~,$ so $$L[t^{3/2}]= \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac {3}{2}+1\right)}{s^\frac {5}{2}}=\frac{\frac {3}{2}\cdot\Gamma \left(\frac {3}{2}\right)}{s^\frac {5}{2}}=\frac{\frac {3}{2}\cdot\frac {1}{2}\cdot\Gamma \left(\frac {1}{2}\right)}{s^\frac {5}{2}}=\frac{\frac {3}{4}\cdot\sqrt \pi}{s^\frac {5}{2}}=\dfrac{3\sqrt \pi}{4}s^{-5/2}~.$$
as $~ Γ(n+1)=nΓ(n)~$ and $~Γ(1/2)=\sqrt \pi~.$

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was my mistake not take a look at the formula properly

Comment: You are welcome. Be careful next time. Have a nice day.